# Sonarqube closes randomly

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I just installed sonarqube 6.2 on a linux server with a postgres database.

I had troubles with some databases disconnections that I apparently fixed by decommenting in the config :

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=60
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

But the server keep closing randomly (~1-2h after it starts) with nothing on the logs,

```
==> logs/ce.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:38 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process

==> logs/sonar.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:38 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is stopping

==> logs/ce.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:39 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine shutting down...

==> logs/sonar.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:41 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is stopped
2017.01.05 15:40:41 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping

==> logs/es.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:42 INFO  es[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2017.01.05 15:40:42 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] stopping ...
2017.01.05 15:40:42 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] stopped
2017.01.05 15:40:42 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] closing ...
2017.01.05 15:40:42 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] closed

==> logs/sonar.log <==
2017.01.05 15:40:43 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

My first guess was that it might be a problem with database connexion timeouts ? But the database is installed on the same machine, and it stops really randomly :

```
2017.01.05 03:07:14 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up
2017.01.05 05:38:06 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is stopping

2017.01.05 11:07:53 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up
2017.01.05 12:36:52 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is stopping

2017.01.05 14:22:03 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up
2017.01.05 15:40:38 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is stopping
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

EDIT : It just crashed while I was using it, the server is swaping a lot, I will try to free some ram (btw I have `sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server` and no dump showed)

Comment: You should check that the file `$SONARQUBE_HOME/temp/sharedmemory ` is not deleted or touched by another process. Note that the path to temp directory can be configured with property `sonar.path.temp`

Comment: Is there any way I can "see" this ? I can clearly see in the logs the server is shutting down, what i'm missing is the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such shutdown of SQ on Linux have been explained in the past by the Linux process "[OOM killer](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit3MCE1a3RAhXKWBoKHeAsBO8QFggcMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.ubuntu-fr.org%2Foomkiller&usg=AFQjCNFV5G-P4RLbIo6on1-9naUmvxH5Xw&sig2=diVsFBQks8BOSplHSIrG1Q&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d24)" killing any of the 4 JVM of SQ (here it seems to be the CE's JVM) because the system is running out of memory.

You should ensure that you haven't configure SQ (by adding the max heap of each process) to consume more memory than available on the system.

Comment: I installed sonarqube exactly the same way on another server which had free ram and it didn't shutdown since then. Thanks for the answer and the knowledge about OOM Killer :)